# How to write csv of list of dictionaries with python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, data-analysis

```
print(test[0].keys())
keys = test[0].keys()
with open('work.csv', 'w') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(test)

def get_user_category(user_polarity, followers_polarity, following_polarity):
if user_polarity and followers_polarity == following_polarity:
    return following_polarity
elif user_polarity and following_polarity == followers_polarity:
    return followers_polarity
elif followers_polarity and following_polarity == user_polarity:
    return user_polarity 

def get_users_tweet(username):
user_tweet = user_csv[user_csv["user"] == username]["tweets"]
user_tweet = list(user_tweet)
return user_tweet

def convertDictToCSV(dictionary):
w = csv.writer(open("output.csv", "w"))
for key, val in dictionary.items():
    w.writerow([key,val])
    return "Written to csv"

def get_maximum_class(username):
l = []
w = {}
for x in user_csv[user_csv["user"] == username ]["labels"]:
    l.append(x)
for z in set(l):
    w[z] = l.count(z)
return max(w)

def get_maximum_class_for_followers(username):
l = []
w = {}
for x in followers_csv[followers_csv["user"] == username ]["labels"]:
    l.append(x)
for z in set(l):
    w[z] = l.count(z)
return max(w)

def get_maximum_class_for_followed_users(username):
l = []
w = {}
for x in follow_csv[follow_csv["follows"] == username ]["labels"]:
    l.append(x)
for z in set(l):
    w[z] = l.count(z)
return max(w)
```

def get_followers_and_class_max(user):
    majority = []
    user_followers = set(followers_csv[followers_csv["follows"] == user]["user"])
    user_followers_class = set(followers_csv[followers_csv["follows"] == user]["labels"])
    for each_user in user_followers:
        majority.append(get_maximum_class_for_followers(each_user))
    return max(majority)

```
def get_follow_follow_max(user):
majority = []
users_followed = set(follow_csv[follow_csv["user"] == user]["follows"])
users_followed_class = set(follow_csv[follow_csv["user"] == user]["follows"])
for each_user in users_followed:
    majority.append(get_maximum_class_for_followed_users(each_user))
return max(majority)
```

test = []
for each_user in set(user_csv["user"]):
    try:
        followers_polarity = get_followers_and_class_max(each_user)
    except(ValueError):
        followers_polarity = 0
    try:
        following_polarity = get_follow_follow_max(each_user)
    except(ValueError):
        following_polarity = 0

```
user_category = get_user_category(get_maximum_class(each_user), followers_polarity, following_polarity)
users_tweet = get_users_tweet(each_user)
data = {"User:": each_user, "Polarity: ": get_maximum_class(each_user), "Following Polarity: ": following_polarity,            "Followers Polarity: ": followers_polarity, "Users Category: ": user_category }
test.append(data)
```

## print(test)

```
new_file =StringIO(newline='')   

#print(test[0].keys())
keys = test[0].keys()
with open('work.csv', 'w') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(test)
with open('work3','w',newline='') as f_out:
    f_out.write(output_file.getvalue())
```

i want to create a new csv file with new fields. the classification is displaying on the terminal but not creating a new csv file.

Comment: What exactly do you wish to display on the terminal ? Your question isn't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `StringIO` class ([docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO)) to write to memory (without creating any file) and then write to terminal. This example will write CSV data to `StringIO` object and prints it:

```
import csv
from io import StringIO   # from StringIO import StringIO in case of Python2

test = [{'col1':1, 'col2':2, 'col3':3},
        {'col1':4, 'col2':5, 'col3':6}]

output_file = StringIO(newline='')

dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
dict_writer.writeheader()
dict_writer.writerows(test)

output_file.seek(0)
print(output_file.read())
```

Prints:

```
col1,col2,col3
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

Edit:

For writing to multiple CSV files you can use this snippet:

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

test = [{'col1':1, 'col2':2, 'col3':3},
        {'col1':4, 'col2':5, 'col3':6}]

output_file = StringIO(newline='')

dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
dict_writer.writeheader()
dict_writer.writerows(test)

with open('work1.csv', 'w', newline='') as f1_out, \
    open('work2.csv', 'w', newline='') as f2_out:

    f1_out.write(output_file.getvalue())
    f2_out.write(output_file.getvalue())
```

This will create two files `work1.csv` and `work2.csv`.

Comment: i meant to say save the output into a new csv file. thanks for the explanation